# The selection cannot be launches ,and there are no recent launches

Tags: android

I have updated eclipse,but after that,When I click the "Run " button, I get the following message.
"The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches."
I have searched a lot and cannot correct the error..Pls help me..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you want to debug the project right-click on it in the **Package Explorer** navigate to Debug As and select Java Application. If you are given multiple classes which can server as the entry-point, you will have to make an educated decision as to which class it is.

So Do onething like:

Right-click the **Main** class in the Package Explorer at left, then choose Run As, Java Application.

If it doesn't help you then there is a different way as well:

1: Just remove the project from the **workspace** and,

2:  under the **local filesystem** list in the project explorer, right-click the folder of the project and

3:  click **Promote to project**.

This will might help you..

Comment: As i told you that in the left hand side open project explorer. And then right click on the main class(main java). After that you will get an option like run as and then click on android application. Now let me know.

Comment: After right click on the main class(main java)from project explorer,i cannot see any option like run as  or debug.

Comment: Ok then try 2nd one as i mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you are able to view the option Android SDK Manager in Window menu.
2. If not, download the required tools through Help menu > Install software. Download the softwares required for Android app development, then you will be able to run your project only.

Tell me if it still does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I was trying to run program using :

public static void  man ()
instead of          main()
check for mistakes in code , probably it will work .