# Why does "the selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches" notice come out in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Why does "the selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches" notice is coming out in this case?

```
module try {
    public class module-info {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            System.out.println("hello"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your file in a Source Folder in a Java Project, both of those terms in the sense that Eclipse's Java tools use them?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a 'module-info.java' file? The module info has a completely different format and does not contain Java classes. This should be giving you compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse gave me the same error message for my project. "The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches."

I navigated to Run menu –> Run Configurations... –> Java Application –> Launch Configuration –> Run. This ran my project without the error message.

Please see also the question, "[The selection cannot be launches, and there are no recent launches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782107/the-selection-cannot-be-launches-and-there-are-no-recent-launches)" for Android.